# File upload using html, Ajax, java

Tags: java, html, ajax, file, upload

I would like to use ajax for file upload to the server using servlet.

I'm using HTML as front end.

Here is my code:

```
<form id=lii_form  method="post" action="/MyServlet?action=uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="lii_fu" id="lii_fu" size=100 />
            &nbsp; &nbsp; 
            <input type=button name=lii_fileupload value=Upload id=lii_fileupload onclick="uploadFile();" />
         </form>
```

Here is my JS code.

```
function uploadFile() {
var filename = $("#lii_fu").val();
var d = new Date();


if(filename == '' ) {
    alert("Please select file and try uploading it");
    return;
} else {
    $.ajax({url:"/MDMGlobal/PsInvoiceServlet?action=uploadFile&ts=" + d.getTime(),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            success:function(result){
           //alert(result);
           var response = eval('(' + result + ')');

           var flag = response.success;
           if(flag) {// == 'true') {

             alert("File successfully uploaded");

             var files = response.invoiceUploadedFiles;

             if(files != '' && files != 'undefined') {
                 var stt = "<br /><Table width=350 class=pubssubs border=0 >";
                 stt += "<tr><td width=300>" + files + "</td><td width=50><img src=\"/app/images/delete.gif\" border=0 onclick=\"deleteFile()\"/></td></tr>" ;
                 stt += "</table>";

                 document.getElementById("lii_uploadedFiles").innerHTML  = stt;
             }
           } else {
             alert("Error occurred while uploading the file...");
           }

          }, error:function () {
              //$('#spinner').fadeOut('slow');
              $body = $("body");
                        $body.removeClass("loading");
              alert("Error occurred while uploading the file");
          },
          beforeSend: function() {
              //alert("before send");
              //$('#spinner').fadeIn('slow');
              $body = $("body");
                $body.addClass("loading");
          },
          complete: function() {
              //$('#spinner').fadeOut('slow');
              $body = $("body");
                $body.removeClass("loading");
          }});
}
```

}

Here is my servlet code:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
        out = response.getWriter();
        MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request,".", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
        f = multi.getFile("lii_fu");
        String fname=multi.getOriginalFileName("lii_fu");
        System.out.println(fname);

        fname = dttmp + "_" + fname;

        request.getSession(true).setAttribute("invoiceUploadedFiles", fname);

        String outputfile = "\\path_to_file_save\\" + fname;

        fi = new FileInputStream(f);

        byte[] b = null;

        fi.read(b);

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
        outputStream.write(b);
        outputStream.close();                 
        System.out.println("File saved");
```

When i select file and click on 'upload' it's giving below error:

**java.io.IOException: Posted content type isn't multipart/form-data**

Can anybody help me to fix the problem or any alternate solution also good but based on html and ajax, java.

Comment: you didn't provide any data in your ajax request. please, read jquery ajax documentation carefully.

Comment: What it should be? Can you please help to give the code syntax as per the code what i have?